# ASP.NET Core Web App 6.0, Index view not found, but exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am using VS2022, and I tried creating ASP.NET Core Web App (Model - View - Controller) template, with Framework version 6.0.

After creating a project, and trying to start it (without changing literally anything), I receive this error -

[image]

Even tho, I have this view in my project (it was automatically generated) -
[image]

**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by updating Visual Studio to a 17.1.3. version, from 17.0.4!

Comment: I suddenly started facing a similar problem in my Production environment. Upgrading Visual Studio and doing another publish fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open .csproj you will found a view with Remove tag. delete the Remove tag and everything wills start to work.

[Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25157#issuecomment-1178638119)